# Group values by another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, aggregate

I have  the following code

```
ID | Name | Salary
---|------|-------
1  | Tom  | 100
2  | Tom  | 200
3  | Max  | 200
4  | Jim  | 100
5  | Max  |  50
6  | Tom  | 300
7  | Jim  | 200
```

I'm trying to get those IDs from usernames which have the max salary.
Expected result:

```
ID | Name 
---|------
6  | Tom 
3  | Max 
7  | Jim
```

What I've tried without success:

```sql
SELECT ID, Name FROM Employee WHERE ID IN 
(
    SELECT ID, FROM Employee GROUP BY Salary HAVING MAX(Salary)
)
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to phrase this problem is to join your `Employee` table to a subquery which identifies the max salary for each name.

```
SELECT e1.ID, e1.Name
FROM Employee e1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Name, MAX(Salary) AS max_salary
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY Name
) e2
    ON e1.Name = e2.Name AND e1.Salary = e2.max_salary;
```

### Demo

We can also approach this problem using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT e1.ID, e1.Name
FROM Employee e1
WHERE e1.Salary = (SELECT MAX(e2.Salary) FROM Employee e2
                   WHERE e1.Name = e2.Name);
```

To round off this answer, assuming you are using SQL Server and have access to `ROW_NUMBER`, we can write the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Salary DESC) rn
    FROM Employee
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `IN` at the 2nd approach? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad1f1c/5

Comment: @Shneeg That's an interesting way of writing the second query, and one which would only run on MySQL, as far as I know.  I believe that under the hood that query would perform similarly the first query which uses a join.  So yes, it might outperform the correlated approach I have above.

Comment: If you feel you need a lot more information, you may open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily with a window function:

```
select id, name, salary, 
from (
  select id, name, salary, 
         max(salary) over () as max_salary
  from employee
) t
where salary = max_salary
order by name;
```

You didn't state your DBMS, but the above is standard SQL. This is typically faster than joining to a derived table with an extra `group by`

Comment: Funny: I could have sworn I saw the MySQL tag.  Now that I look again, I just see SQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Even MySQL finally arrived in the 21st century: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Comment: Yeah, heard about that.  Get ready to start losing your accepted MySQL answers, as trolls start posting window function queries.